# GCTime Stamps Not printed

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I run the java application with following configuration

```
-Xmx512M
-Xms32M
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintGCDetails  
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-Xloggc:Desktop/Gen/Gen/gc.log
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime
-XX:+PrintGC
```

But it is not printing GCTimeStamps in gc.log file..

The gc.log file contents are like below..

```
Application time: 0.0272860 seconds

2015-01-23T17:18:14.054+0100: 0.731: [GC [PSYoungGen: 94627K->58213K(108928K)] 226219K->217525K(287744K), 0.0607860 secs] [Times: user=0.35 sys=0.12, real=0.06 secs]
2015-01-23T17:18:14.115+0100: 0.792: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 58213K->38649K(108928K)] [PSOldGen: 159312K->178815K(251904K)] 217525K->217465K(360832K) [PSPermGen: 4237K->4237K(21248K)], 0.1840190 secs] [Times: user=0.18 sys=0.01, real=0.19 secs]

Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.2449170 seconds

Application time: 0.0107920 seconds
```

Comment: Out of interest - do the timestamps appear if you remove -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps

Comment: In some way time is included in date, isn't it enough for your ?

Answer (score 1):

From your log

```
Application time: 0.0272860 seconds
```

Line above is produced by `-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime`, no date stamp

```
2015-01-23T17:18:14.054+0100: 0.731: [GC [PSYoungGen: 94627K->58213K(108928K)] 226219K->217525K(287744K), 0.0607860 secs] [Times: user=0.35 sys=0.12, real=0.06 secs]
2015-01-23T17:18:14.115+0100: 0.792: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 58213K->38649K(108928K)] [PSOldGen: 159312K->178815K(251904K)] 217525K->217465K(360832K) [PSPermGen: 4237K->4237K(21248K)], 0.1840190 secs] [Times: user=0.18 sys=0.01, real=0.19 secs]
```

Lines above are produced by `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`, date stamps are they

```
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.2449170 seconds
```

Line above is produced by `-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStopedTime`, no date stamp

```
Application time: 0.0107920 seconds
```

Line above is produced by `-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime`, no date stamp

**In summary**

`-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps` works only with output produced by `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`

Output `-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime` and `-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime` cannot be prefixed with date stamps unfortunately

You can find more details about GC diagnostic options [here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2013/11/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html).